# Twilio - is it feasible to use application transfer as an application type

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to use application transfer as an application type

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/applications

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I am not sure what you are asking here, can you expand on your question or give me an example of what you mean, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.